# Any guidance on how to create n2cms add-ons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, n2, n2cms

I'm going to create a new add-on for my n2 based website, but I can't find any useful documentation on how to do that, can you please provide some primary guidance (quick steps) about how the add-on project structure should be, and the involved classes that i should inherit from?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In january they released the developer documentation here http://n2cms.codeplex.com/releases/view/59307.

Look into how other add-ons are structured https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms/commits/blogaddon.

Comment: The documentation is still incomplete, but you're right, I should look into how existing ones were written.

Comment: There is newer documentation available here: https://n2cmsdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/display/N2CMS/